# Remove files from remote host using SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

I need to delete all files inside a remote directory using SSH,

The directory itself must not be deleted, so @Wes' answer is not what I need. If it was a  local directory, I would run `rm -rf dir/*`.

Comment: @Wes's answer can be easily adapted to your needs - just add the `/*` at the end. It's hardly a complex command to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According man of `ssh` on my machine:

```
If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead 
of a login shell.
```

This means that shell expansion of command passed by ssh won't be done on remote side.
Therefore we need "self contained" command, which doesn't relay on shell expansion.

```
ssh user@remote-machine "find /path/to/directory -type f -exec rm {} \;"
```

Here all the job for finding files to be deleted is done exclusively by `find`, without help from shell.

Some similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/215825/remotely-running-find-exec-options)

Answer (score 17):

It's as simple as:

```
ssh HOSTNAME rm -rf "/path/to/the/directory/*"
```

Comment: as with any other command, pratically. Just say ssh hostname, and then the command you want to execute. Very handy for eg. doing remote backups/dumps etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
ssh HOSTNAME "sh -c 'rm -rf /path/to/the/directory/*'"
```

Note that you need to enclose the remote command with double quotes and the pathname with single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all files from directory hierarchy:

```
ssh user@HOSTNAME 'rm $(find /path/to/directory -type f)'
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass in a list of files? I have a folder locally called ./deleteme and I want to delete all files in ./deleteme from the remote server.

Comment: That's very dangerous because it breaks on files with spaces in their name.

Comment: @slhck  Right, one should either not use spaces in filenames or use  dimbas's solution which is better.